# Cannot create a stop list in SQl 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm new to the stop list functionality in SQL 2008 and seem to be missing something obvious. I'm trying to exectue the following statement:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST myStoplist3  
FROM SYSTEM STOPLIST;  
GO
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1  
Incorrect syntax near 'STOPLIST'.
```

Any ideas? The code is lifted straight out of MSDN so I'm assuming it's a configuration issue - full text search is set up and working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably stating the obvious here but make sure the compatibility level for you database is set to 100 (SQL 2008) as well. Just in case its been set for 90 (SQL 2005) or lower.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks! I knew it would be something stupid like that!
Slightly depressed this question will now forever be linked with my profile!

Comment: Andrew these are the sort of issues we can all fall down on which makes it a good question. +1 for your question.

Comment: Yes, thanks, both the question and answer were helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is fine - how are you executing the statement? Because if you're executing it from code then you need to remove the 'GO', as GO is not a SQL Keyword, it's a special token that is interpreted by client applications (e.g. management studio) to mean 'now send this batch to the server'.

Comment: I'm executing this from within Management Studio so the GO is in context.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the appropriate permissions to create fulltext indices?